# JAVA Reversing a string on multiple lines output

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, reverse

Why in my program am i getting the output on one single line ? like abc123... I want my output to be printed on multiple lines, same as my inputs..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 class Reverse
 {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String original;
      String reverse = "";

      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

      while (kbd.hasNextLine()) {
        original = kbd.nextLine();

        int length = original.length();
        for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {

       reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
        }
      }
        System.out.println(reverse);
   }
 }
```

It should be for example like this :

```
input: abc
       123
       ...
output:cba
       321
       ...
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Reverse {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String original;
        String reverse = "";

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);


        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        while (kbd.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            original = kbd.nextLine();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(original);
            output.append(sb.reverse().toString()).append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

***EDIT*** I noticed that in your question it seems that you only want to print the output after all input has been provided. I've modified the code from my original answer to do this.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not how i want it, I want to keep typing all the inputs on multiple lines, and then press CTRL+D to reach EOF and get all the outputs on multiple lines.. 
Thanks for your help anyways

Comment: Have another look at the code. I was updating it as you were commenting :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! thats exactly how i wanted it ! appreciate it

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help. If this answer worked for you, could you accept it please?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class reverseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input="";
        System.out.println("Enter the input string");
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            input = br.readLine();
            char[] try1= input.toCharArray();
            for (int i=try1.length-1;i>=0;i--)
            System.out.print(try1[i]);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 package stackoverflow;
    import java.util.Scanner;
     class Reverse
     {
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
          String original;
          String reverse = "";

          Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

          while (kbd.hasNextLine()) {
            original = kbd.nextLine();
            //befor you add the reversed string add a jump line firs
            if(reverse.length()>0)reverse=reverse+"\n";

            int length = original.length();
            for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {

           reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
            }
          }
            System.out.println(reverse);
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change this part

```
for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
  reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
}
```

in

```
for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
  reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
}
reverse = reverse + '\n';
```

This will add new line character.

I have one advice for you - use `StringBuilder` for new reverse string
Like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String original;
    StringBuilder sbReverse = new StringBuilder();

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (kbd.hasNextLine()) {
        original = kbd.nextLine();

        int length = original.length();
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sbReverse.append(original.charAt(i));
        }
        sbReverse.append('\n');
    }

    System.out.println(sbReverse.toString());
}
```

The reason - in Java, strings are immutable. 
That mean every time it execute `reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);` it will be created a new string in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the output in a single line because you are using `System.out.printf()`. Use `System.out.println()` instead.

PS: an easier way to reverse a string would be to use reverse() from StringBuilder.

```
reverse = new StringBuilder(original).reverse().toString();
```